# Socket.io event disconnect is not being called

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a chat project. When i'm frequently refreshing the page(more than 1 time per second) the `socket.on('disconnect'..` is not being called, so i have this `null` or extra users, who were disconnected but are still remaining in the chat. This chat is without authorization, so every time you are connected you get new randomly generated id.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log(user_id + " DISCONNECTED");
```

this console log is not called when i disconnect reloading the page very quickly.

Comment: The disconnect can be unreliable.  Even though you are not authenticating, you can still give the user a cookie when they first join.  If they refresh without a disconnect, check for the cookie and reissue the same user_id.